# How to automate the Lastpass CLI login process

Tags: authentication, automation, command-line-interface, lastpass, passwordvault

I was wondering if anyone successfully automated the LastPass CLI login process. I cannot seem to get around the password prompt, which I need to automate to make it useful.

I've tried commands like

```
echo <password> | lpass login <username>
```

or

```
yes <password> | lpass login <username>
```

I keep getting output saying the password is not correct. Has anyone automated this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would probably need to disable the pinetry password prompt so that lpass reads your password from standard input.

As the man pages say:

> If pinentry program is unavailable, or if the LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY environment variable is set to 1, passwords will be read from standard input and a prompt will be displayed on standard error.

Meaning: It should work if you run it like this:

```
echo <password> | LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY=1 lpass login <username>
```

Or by just setting the environment variable for your shell (`export LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY=1` in your `~/.profile` or similar)

Comment: Thank! this worked! Could you send me a link where you found this info?

Comment: [lastpass-cli man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/lastpass-cli/lpass.1.en.html#Password_Entry) under `Password Entry`

Comment: Thx! totally missed that part. Do you also know how to echo multiple arguments to the login command. When I have an account that has two factor authentication enabled the login fails; something like `echo <password> \n <otp> | LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY=1 lpass login <username>`

Comment: `LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY=1 lpass login --trust --force <username> <<STDIN
<password>
<otp>
STDIN`

Comment: Do not forget to insert line endings in the command above: $"LPASS_DISABLE_PINENTRY=1 lpass login --force {credentials.Username} <<STDIN\n{credentials.Password}\n{otp}\nSTDIN\n";